# Store objects in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have few Objects in an object obj which I want to store in array.I am implementing push() for this case but it isn't giving correct output. Can someone suggest the approach to implement the same.

```
var obj ={
car:{
maruti: {wheels: 4, mileage:15},
dezire: {wheels: 4, mileage:19}
    },

bike:{
suzuki:{wheels: 2, mileage:45},
honda:{wheels: 2, mileage:85}
     } 
         }
```

Expected Output:

```
var obj ={
car:[{
maruti: {wheels: 4, mileage:15},
dezire: {wheels: 4, mileage:19}
    }],

bike:[{
suzuki:{wheels: 2, mileage:45},
honda:{wheels: 2, mileage:85}
     } 
         }]
```

Comment: If you want array you should have something like this `obj ={
car:[{name: 'maruti', details: {wheels: 4, mileage:15}}, {name: 'dezire', details:  {wheels: 4, mileage:19}}],` it make no sense to have array with object and keys inside. But most up voted answer give you just that.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the object's keys to an object with its value in an array like so:

```js
const obj = {car:{maruti:{wheels:4,mileage:15},dezire:{wheels:4,mileage:19}},bike:{suzuki:{wheels:2,mileage:45},honda:{wheels:2,mileage:85}}},

res = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => ({...acc, [key]:[obj[key]]}), {});
console.log(res);
```

However, do note, objects don't store a guaranteed order, and thus the resulting object may be in a different order to your input.

Comment: Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => { obj[e].sort( (a,b) =>{ return Object.values(a)[0][0].mileage- Object.values(b)[0][0].mileage }) }) can i sort this object now on the basis of mileage in this manner and get maruti and dezire sorted inside car and suzuki and honda in bike   @Nick Parsons

Answer (score 0):

just you need to put `[]` around ur each value of `obj`.

```js
var obj ={
car:{
    maruti: {wheels: 4, mileage:15},
     dezire: {wheels: 4, mileage:19}
},

bike:{
  suzuki:{wheels: 2, mileage:45},
  honda:{wheels: 2, mileage:85}
     } 
}
for(let key in obj){
 obj[key] = [obj[key]]
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => { obj[e].sort( (a,b) =>{ return Object.values(a)[0][0].mileage- Object.values(b)[0][0].mileage }) }) can i sort this object now on the basis of mileage in this manner and get maruti and dezire sorted inside car and suzuki and honda in bike @Maheer Ali

Comment: @Kris you can't sort the `objects`

Comment: Is there any way i can sort this by making it an array of objects @Maheer Ali

Comment: @Kris you wanna sort `car` and `bike` `array`?

Comment: Inside my car object i want to sort maruti and dezire w.r.t the mileage and same applies to the case of bike   @Maheer Ali

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Object.keys()` like so:

```js
 

var obj ={
car:{
maruti: {wheels: 4, mileage:15},
dezire: {wheels: 4, mileage:19}
},

bike:{
suzuki:{wheels: 2, mileage:45},
honda:{wheels: 2, mileage:85}
 } 
     }

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] = [obj[key]]);

console.log(obj);
```

And for sorting the vehicles by mileage:

```js
 

var obj ={
car:{
maruti: {wheels: 4, mileage:15},
dezire: {wheels: 4, mileage:19}
},

bike:{
suzuki:{wheels: 2, mileage:45},
honda:{wheels: 2, mileage:85}
 } 
     }

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] = [obj[key]]);

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key].sort((a, b) => a.mileage - b.mileage));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => { obj[e].sort( (a,b) =>{ return Object.values(a)[0][0].mileage- Object.values(b)[0][0].mileage }) }) can i sort this object now on the basis of mileage in this manner and get maruti and dezire sorted inside car and suzuki and honda in bike   @Jack Bashford

Comment: After implementing sorting of the object you suggested the object  is not maintaining the sorted order . Is there any other way with which we can sort this and the order can also be retained.... may be by turning this object into an array of object .. Can you please help   @Jack Bashford